# Нагрузка PHP-интерпретатора

Tags: php, производительность, интерпретатор

Несколько вопросов к людям, хорошо понимающим работу интерпретатора PHP.

- Сказывается ли на скорости выполнения скрипта количество открывающих дескрипторов? Т.е. в файле смесь из HTML разметки и PHP кода, при этом скажется ли существенно на производительности, если мы будем открывать и закрывать `<? ?>` на каждой строке?

Этот:

```
<?
if( $val > 0 ) {
    echo 'yes';
}
else {
    echo 'no';
}
?>
```

или

```
<? if( $val > 0 ) { ?>
    <? echo 'yes'; ?>
<? } ?>
<? else { ?>
    <? echo 'no'; ?>
<? } ?>
```

- Есть ли разница, по скорости выполнения интерпретатором, классического синтаксиса и альтернативного?

Т.е. между таким:

```
<?
if( $val > 0 ) {
    echo 'yes';
}
else {
    echo 'no';
}
?>
```

и таким:

```
<?
if( $val > 0 ):
    echo 'yes';
else:
    echo 'no';
endif;
?>
```

вариантами.

- Какой из вариантов вывода переменной и результатов функции использует меньше ресурсов, если вообще есть разница?

Этот:

```
<? echo '$value'; ?>
```

или этот:

```
<?=$value?>
```

Comment: @Palmervan это Вы еще темы для wordPress не видели :)

Comment: @shurik видел, но лучше бы невидел!)))

Comment: Да понятно, что в таком виде <? ?> бессмысленны, но это же пример. Вопрос в том, сказывается ли количество дескрипторов в файле на время выполнения. Ведь один и тот же код можно написать используя вставки HTML кода напрямую, при этом закрывая скрипт PHP, или использовать echo. 
Кроме того, иногда просто для читабельности кода удобно увеличивать количество дескрипторов, но вопрос в том, насколько это расточительно в плане ресурсов.

Comment: Как бы там не было -  в шаблонах подобный подход использовать целесообразно, в остальном коде ИМХО - нет, причем не при каких обстоятельствах, кроме неразберихи в коде вы ничего не добавите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?
$e = '';
$st = microtime(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  if (1 > 0) {
    echo $e;
  } else echo $e;
}
echo '<br />'.(microtime(1)-$st);

$st = microtime(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) { ?>
<?  if (1 > 0) { ?>
<? echo $e; ?> 
<?  } else { ?>
<? echo $e; ?>
<? } ?>
<? }
echo '<br />'.(microtime(1)-$st);
echo '<hr />';
$st = microtime(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) { ?>
<?  if (1 > 0) { ?>
<?=$e?> 
<?  } else { ?>
<?=$e?> 
<? } ?>
<? }
echo '<br />'.(microtime(1)-$st);

$st = microtime(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) { ?>
<?  if (1 > 0) { ?>
<? echo $e; ?> 
<?  } else { ?>
<? echo $e; ?>
<? } ?>
<? }
echo '<br />'.(microtime(1)-$st);
echo '<hr />';
?>
```

Результат:

```
0.08100700378418
2.4613921642303
----
3.0508909225464
2.4576618671417
```

Последние 2 менялись от "1.5/6" до "4/1", так что скорее одинаковые. А вот первая пара - говорящая)

**UPDATE, синтаксис**

```
<?
$e = '';
$st = microtime(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  if (1 > 0) {
    echo $e;
  } else echo $e;
}
echo '<br />'.(microtime(1)-$st);

$st = microtime(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
  if (1 > 0):
    echo $e;
  else:
    echo $e;
  endif;
}
echo '<br />'.(microtime(1)-$st);
echo '<hr />';
?>

0.089139938354492
0.082063913345337
```

Comment: Вообще оно логично, потом что по сути `?> <? echo 'a'; ?> <?` получается эквивалентно `echo ' '; echo 'a'; echo ' ';` + надо еще прочитать этот отрезок между `?>` и `<?`.

Comment: Ну да, согласен, что логично. Получается, что "переобращение" к интерпретатору даром не проходит, что и следовало ожидать.

Answer (score 4):

По моему это "экономия на спичках" и вряд ли кто-нибудь даст точный  и правильный ответ

Comment: Я все же надеюсь, что найдется гуру=)) Пожалуй, что "на спичках", но как показывает мой опыт, иногда, мелочи оказываются очень даже важны.

Comment: Померять время не пробовали ?

Comment: неа, не пробовал, но мне кажется, чтобы увидеть разницу, нужен достаточно большой скрипт, одинаковый по функционалу, но написанный в разном стиле. Я все же надеюсь, что есть люди, которые знают ответ на этот вопрос.